# How do I get $-2$ as a solution to $\frac{3x+1}{x+2}<2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm stuck at this seemingly simple problem again.

Solve the difference
$$\frac{3x+1}{x+2}<2$$

I try to solve this in the intuitive way:

$$\frac{3x+1}{x+2}<2$$
$$=>3x+1<2(x+2)$$
$$=>3x+1<2x+4$$
$$=>x<3$$

I then read that the solution is $-2<x<3$

Where in the world did they get that $-2$ from?

Comment: Make it homogeneous by moving $2$ to the left and simplifying to get: $\frac{x-3}{x+2}<0$. Now you see the zeros $-2$ and $3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you can't multiply both sides by $(x+2)$ as it might be negative for certain values of $x$ and that would require reversing the inequality sign. Try multiplying both sides by $(x+2)^2$ instead and see if the resulting quadratic leads anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

When you multiply by something negative, the inequality sign flips. So when you go from
$$
\frac{3x+1}{x+2}<2
$$
to
$$
3x+1<2(x+2)
$$
without changing the inequality sign, you're implicitly assuming that $x+2>0$. For $x+2<0$, we instead get
$$
3x+1>2(x+2)
$$

Answer (score 0):

You should notice that you could only multiply both sides by $x+2$ and preserve the inequality sign as $3x+1<2(x+2)$ if and only if $x+2>0$. Otherwise, the inequality sign will change since you multiply both sides by a negative number